# Extraer datos de XML usando Python

Tags: python, xml, revisión-de-código

Tengo este código y necesito extraer los condes de comentario de los datos XML, calcular (http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228073.xml) la suma de los números en el archivo y escriba la suma.

Me gustaría saber qué parte código necesito introducir porque yo ya había utilizado diferentes códigos para extraer la suma de los números

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
    print data
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)

    results = tree.findall('result')
    lat = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lat').text
    lng = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lng').text
    location = results[0].find('formatted_address').text

    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
    print location
```

Comment: Lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es extraer la cantidad de comentarios `comments_228073.xml` por persona. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: Si, efectivamente. Tengo que extraer los códigos de los comentarios de los datos XML, calcular la suma de éstos y que se escriba la suma.

Comment: Hola, sobre el código que has puesto en tu pregunta, no entiendo cuál es la relación con el XML que mencionas en el primer párrafo

Answer (score 4):

Con este código puedes extraer los números dentro del tag `count`, que asumo son la cantidad de comentarios por usuario, y luego sumarlos:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228073.xml'
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
commentinfo = ET.fromstring(data)
count_sum = sum([int(comment.find('count').text) for comment in commentinfo[1]])
print(count_sum)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya tienes la solución de Javier usando `ElementTree`, ese módulo puede parecer un poco complicado de usar al principio. Existen otras alternativas más sencillas que podrías probar.

---

## untangle

El módulo [untangle](https://github.com/stchris/untangle) convierte XML a objetos Python, la ventaja es que puedes pasarle directamente la URL. Para instalar:

```
$ pip install untangle
```

**Solución:**

```
import untangle

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228073.xml'
parsed_data = untangle.parse(url)
comments = parsed_data.commentinfo.comments.comment
total = sum([int(comment.count.cdata) for comment in comments])
```

---

## xmltodict

El módulo [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) te permite trabajar con XML como si estuvieras trabajando con JSON. Para instalar:

```
$ pip install xmltodict
```

**Solución:**

```
import urllib2
import xmltodict

url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228073.xml'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
parsed_data = xmltodict.parse(data.read())
comments = parsed_data['commentinfo']['comments']['comment']
total = sum([int(comment['count']) for comment in comments])
```

Comment: Gracias César. Desconocía este modulo y su trabajo con XML

Comment: Que hay de tablib???