# Cómo procesar XML en Python: 5 posibles alternativas ¿y todas fallan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-requests

¿Qué posibilidades de procesar un documento XML existen en Python? Les propongo repasar las más destacadas hoy por hoy a través de unos documentos XML que se resisten a ser procesados. Veamos:

Tomaré como fuente de XML la de ésta página:

[Partidos de Tenis](https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis)

Que nos permite consultar una base de datos y dependiendo de los parámetros que se le apliquen a la URL nos devuelve los ficheros XML con la información solicitada; en este caso, tenemos una lista de eventos deportivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para cada evento (`<event></event>`) tenemos, como mínimo, un `<id>`, un nombre (`<name>`), y una información cronológica que describe su comienzo (`<start>`).

Doy por supuesto que *no existen errores en la composición de estos XML*, ya que de existir **se producirían a su vez otros errores en la página que los utiliza**.

Existen muchas y diversas posibilidades de manejar un documento XML, pero para no extendernos innecesariamente me conformaré con poder relacionar cada evento con su ID y con hora de inicio; es decir, el resultado final podría ser un diccionario de Python, como éste:

```
dic_eventos = {1076553300890015:{'name':'Manuel Guinard vs Evgeny Donskoy',
                                 'start':datetime.strptime('2019-03-27T10:23:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')},
               1075839532180015:{'name':'Jurgen Zopp vs Mikael Torpegaard',
                                 'start':datetime.strptime('2019-03-27T10:40:00.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')},
               ....}
```

Pero el problema es que *ni siquiera llegamos a parsear el documento XML*; es decir, no podemos operar con él porque no podemos convertirlo en objetos Python de ningún tipo.

El proceso de descargar el documento XML es trivial:

```
import requests
print(requests.get('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis').text)
```

Se obtiene primero un objeto `Response` y después, aplicando el método `.text`, el contenido del XML en texto plano (`str`).

A continuación les presento las 5 posibilidades de procesamiento de estos documentos que he utilizado y los motivos del fracaso de cada una de ellas.

**Requests_XML+XPath:**

[Página del autor](http://xml.python-requests.org/)

[Ejemplos de uso de XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Código utilizado:

```
from requests_xml import XMLSession

session = XMLSession()

maio = session.get('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis')

eventos = maio.xml.xpath('//event')
```

Excepción producida:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usuario\maio.py", line 37, in <module>
    event = maio.xml.xpath('//event')
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests_xml.py", line 224, in xpath
    selected = self.lxml.xpath(selector)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests_xml.py", line 120, in lxml
    self._lxml = etree.fromstring(self.raw_xml)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3222, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1765, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

**Beautifulsoup+lxml:**

[Página del autor](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id16)

Código utilizado:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

muno = requests.get("https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis")

maio = BeautifulSoup(muno.text, "xml")

print(maio)
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Que no nos sirve, porque no podemos recuperar la información sobre los eventos, que era lo que buscábamos.

**XML.ElementTree:**

[Pregunta de SO-ES en la que me baso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3122/extraer-datos-de-xml-usando-python/3146)

Código utilizado:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis"
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
commentinfo = ET.fromstring(data)
```

Excepción producida:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/usuario/maio.py", line 48, in <module>
    commentinfo = ET.fromstring(data)
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

**Eval():**

Ya que tenemos un objeto `str` que es ‘casi’ como un diccionario en Python, se podría plantear la posibilidad de convertirlo efectivamente en un diccionario:

```
import requests

maio = requests.get("https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=mlb&in-running-flag=false")

print((eval(maio.text)))
```

Pero no, desafortunadamente tampoco es posible:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/usuario/maio.py", line 56, in <module>
    print((eval(maio.text)))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

**XMLtodict:**

[Pregunta de SO-ES en la que me baso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3122/extraer-datos-de-xml-usando-python/3146)

Código utilizado:

```
import urllib.request
import xmltodict

url = "https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
parsed_data = xmltodict.parse(data.read())
```

Excepción producida:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/usuario/maio.py", line 36, in <module>
    parsed_data = xmltodict.parse(data.read())
  File "C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xmltodict.py", line 327, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

Después de todo este via crucis, comprenderán que me parezca como mínimo una proeza el procesamiento de documentos XML en Python. Pero no creo que con esto haya quedado demostrado que es imposible llevarlo a cabo; seguro que es posible. Y seguro que habrá múltiples detalles que estarán pasando desapercibidos para mí. ¿Les resultan evidentes a Vds?

Comment: Lo que veo es que siempre tenes el mismo error, en el mismo lugar. Estas seguro que ese archivo es correcto? y no tiene basura adelante? y como otro tema, cual es la pregunta?

Comment: @gbianchi Entiendo que debe ser correcto porque se utiliza para cargar datos de la página Web de Matchbook (XHR). Lo que necesito es formar un diccionario con la información de los eventos (ID, fecha/hora, participantes...) pero antes que eso hay que procesar esos XML de alguna manera.

Comment: Lo que me extraña es que siempre da error en la linea 1... estas seguro que el archivo esta bien? lo probaste con un archivo que hayas hecho a mano? aunque sea con pocos datos de ese xml, pero armado por vos?

Comment: Los errores dicen que el XML no tiene un `<` al inicio y que no es procesable. ¿Has probado a ver el código del XML descargado?

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Hay alguna forma de comprobarlo? , @Pablo Lozano Lo he guardado en mi disco duro y lo he abierto con el bloc de notas y me aparecen igual que en el navegador, con los `<` incluidos.

Comment: Si, miralo con un programa que te permita ver en binario. Lo mas probable es que no veas delante del < que hay basura.

Comment: Estuve viendo el archivo que comentas y lo pude ver con la estructura desde Google chrome, y si lo descargo también se ve la estructura en xml. Ten en cuenta que estás trayendo un archivo .json  y es el navegador el que te arma la estructura. Probando tu print(request.get()), si te fijas no trae un archivo en xml, supongo que es por esto que no funcionan estas alternativas que comentas. Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Me estaba quedando son caracteres jajaja, prueba descargar el archivo que te genera el Google chrome y este archivo procésalo con alguna de tus alternativas. esto es solo para ver si funcionan y descartar que el problema sea que traigas los datos internamente con python

Comment: @gbianchi Ahora mismo estoy desde el móvil y no puedo verlo, pero ¿qué ocurre si encuentro esa basura? ¿Qué debería hacer?

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda ¡Muchas gracias! ¿Entonces lo correcto sería procesarlo como un JSON en vez de como un XML?

Comment: o hacer la conversion de json a xml con python, ahí no me manejo mucho pero encontré este link buscando -> https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml . Ve cómo te resulta. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que el servidor al que accedes está examinando la cabecera `Accept` que tu cliente le envía para decidir si te responde con JSON o con XML.

Cuando pruebas desde el navegador, éste envía junto con la petición la cabecera

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

en la que expresa su preferencia de recibir la respuesta en html, y si no en xhtml, y si no en xml, y si no ya en cualquier otro formato. El servidor obedece estas preferencias y le responde con un documento XML.

En cambio, cuando pruebas desde Python usando `requests`, esta biblioteca por defecto envía esta otra cabecera:

```
Accept: */*
```

que indica que no tiene preferencias en cuanto al formato y le vale cualquiera. Para este caso se ve que el servidor **decider enviar la respuesta en JSON**, y de ahí que todos tus intentos de analizarlo como XML hayan sido infructuosos.

Basta que envíes la cabecera apropiada para recibir el documento en XML, es decir:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis'
r = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "application/xml"})
```

y en `r.content` tendrías el documento XML.

De todas formas, como ya te han indicado en otra respuesta, el JSON puede ser mucho más simple de procesar. Si no estás obligado a trabajar con el XML, yo preferiría usar la respuesta json.

Comment: La elijo como mejor respuesta porque es la que indica el origen más profundo del problema. No sólo me da la solución, sino que además tengo más información para no cometer el mismo error en el futuro. Esto indica que te has tomado tu tiempo para examinar la cuestión y para mí es lo más importante. Muchas gracias y felicidades.

Comment: @RubenGarcíaTutor Gracias por el comentario. Quisiera aprovechar para felicitarte a ti también por la pregunta, que denota también un importante esfuerzo por tu parte para resolverlo antes de darte por vencido y pedir ayuda. No son frecuentes preguntas tan exhaustivamente investigadas como esta.

Answer (score 4):

Mi respuesta va por el lado de lo que ya te comentaron. Lo que estás recibiendo es un Json y no un xml. Por lo que el tratamiento incluso es un poco más simple:

```
import urllib.request
import json as json

url = "https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

d = json.loads(data.read())
for e in d['events']:
  print(e['id'], e['name'])

1076553296870016 Aslan Karatsev vs Quentin Halys
1075756125600015 Jurgen Melzer vs Pablo Andujar
1076553356490016 Facundo Bagnis vs Gianluca Mager
1076701387430016 Stefano Travaglia vs Nicolas Mahut
1077302532250015 Miami Open Double
1076177074730015 Qiang Wang vs Simona Halep
1069506693330015 WTA Miami 2019
1076413142330015 Gregoire Barrere vs Jelle Sels
1075839531500015 Viktor Troicki vs Mirza Basic
1075978769150016 Daniil Medvedev vs Roger Federer
1070308857800015 ATP Miami 2019
1076864676570015 Roberto Bautista Agut vs John Isner
1076183849220015 Karolina Pliskova vs Marketa Vondrousova
1076739116680016 Felix Auger Aliassime vs Borna Coric
1077338546190016 Alejandro Davidovich Fokina vs Carlos Taberner
1076828485460015 Alessandro Giannessi vs Raul Brancaccio
1077431606420015 Benoit Paire vs Steven Diez
1076828449700016 Dennis Novak vs Antoine Hoang
1076828446190015 Filip Horansky vs Maxime Janvier
1077338563450016 Jiri Vesely vs Andrea Arnaboldi
1077338494290015 Mikael Torpegaard vs Kamil Majchrzak
1076828488980016 Pedro Martinez vs Guillermo Garcia-Lopez
1076828452010015 Ricardas Berankis vs Sebastian Ofner
1077338497410016 Roman Safiullin vs Evgeny Donskoy
1077082658670015 Denis Shapovalov vs Frances Tiafoe
1077047365530015 Anett Kontaveit vs Ashleigh Barty
```

Cualquiera de tus otras opciones debería funcionar, siempre con el supuesto que recibimos un `json`, que interpretamos por medio de `json.loads(<json data>)`, el retorno en este caso, es un diccionario que podremos acceder mediante cualquiera de las técnicas habituales

Siempre es conveniente revisar el contenido "crudo" y ver de que se trata, por ejemplo, para ver los primeros 20 bytes recibidos:

```
print(data.read()[:30])
b'{"offset":0,"per-page":100,"to'
```

Claramente nos damos cuenta que se trataría de un `json` y no un `xml`.

Comment: Esta respuesta es muy buena y de hecho es lo que se pide, pero desgraciadamente no puedo elegir 2. Hay muy buen nivel en SO-ES .De todas formas, está muy bien justificada la diferencia entre JSON y XML, así como los pasos a seguir una vez identificado el problema. Me has ayudado a mí (porque ésta será la solución que implementaré) y ayudarás a cualquier persona que vuelva a encontrarse en la misma situación. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De ninguna forma te hagas problema, por que respuesta aceptas o no. Me basta saber que la misma fu útil. Además siempre es positivo "perder" con @abulafia ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ya.

Acorde a lo conversado.

Tienes la opción de usar [DicttoXml](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml) para convertir de **json a xml** usando Python, yo tengo instalado Anaconda para trabajar con python, lo que me permite ocupar lo que es Anaconda Prompt para hacer instalaciones de modulos.

EL comando es:

```
pip install dicttoxml
```

La página tiene un ejemplo que es valido para python 2.x, yo tengo instalado la version 3.x por lo que el código quedaría así:

```
import json
import urllib.request
import dicttoxml
page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events?language=en&currency=GBP&price-mode=aggregated&exchange-type=back-lay&odds-type=DECIMAL&price-depth=3&price-order=price%20desc&include-event-participants=true&offset=0&per-page=100&market-states=open,suspended,closed&runner-states=open,suspended,closed&tag-url-names=tennis')
content = page.read()
obj = json.loads(content)
print(obj)
{u'mylist': [u'foo', u'bar', u'baz'], u'mydict': {u'foo': u'bar', u'baz': 1}, u'ok': True}
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(obj)
print(xml)
```

Si revisas la terminal primero te va a mostrar el código propio de la página de donde traes los datos y después te va a mostrar la conversión a xml con todas las etiquetas. Puedes probar alguna de tus alternativas pasandoles la variable *xml* de este código.

Saludos

Comment: Fuiste el primero en darse cuenta de que nuestro problema se llamaba JSON y no XML, pero te pido que entiendas que @abulafia fue un paso más allá y explicó por qué nos traían aquél y no éste. En mi caso, puedo seguir adelante con el módulo JSON, pero si alguien necesita obligatoriamente realizar la conversión a XML, seguro que se fijará en tu respuesta. Gracias a tí también.

Comment: si lo lei,y también encuentro que dio una mejor respuesta al trabajar el problema. mi respuesta era básicamente que si viene de una forma, se ocupa una librería y listo, pero el ataca el problema de la raiz que es efectivo. saludos